# How can/ should I process data received by a websocket and call showDialog() in main() function, and give users a visual update

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

**Initial Situation**

I have a [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) application with multiple pages. It is used to control [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) based hardware. Currently I can send commands and receive information via HTTP based requests. While this works great so far, I desire a more flexible and bidirectional solution. I want to get informed about ongoing stuff on my hardware when it happens, not when I make a request.
This is why I set up an websocket on hardwareside, which permanently sends the application status updates (Strings). So far, this works great. I use the [web_socket_channel](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel) package  Since I want to get and process status updates on every page, I thought it would be a good idea to implement the 'listener' on the main function. You can take a look of my implementation here:

```
void main() async {
  final channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse('ws://{LOCAL_IP}/ws'),
  );

  channel.stream.listen((message) {
    print(message); // message 
  });

  runApp(const App());
}
```

On a next step I tried to implement an [AlertDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) to inform users visually. Naturally I tried to replace my *print(message)* with code that should show a AlertDialog:

```
channel.stream.listen((message) {
  if (double.parse(message) > 1337) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,   // IDE throws error here: "Undefined name 'context'"
      builder: (BuildContext context) => const AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Error'),
        content: Text('Number too high'),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Ok'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

So my question is, how can I get access to the context, or implement the functionality to show a dialog window when I get an update from my websocket, independent of the page I am currently on.

Maybe I am far off the usual way, how you would implement such functionality and someone can help me out.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case then what you can do is rather then creating an object in main and listening it right their, you can create a ‘Signleton’ class.

Create a late variable. Initialise it in a function. Now call that function in ‘main()’. So now you have stream which you can listen to anywhere with same object.

Now as for visual part you might be able to get what you want from above explanation. Or if you just want show some toast then you can use bot_toast package it doesn’t require context to show toast message.